# How to create script which will enter password automatically?

Tags: linux, bash

I am creating a script.
I want this script perform next task:
Log in as a root user. (I am trying to use one line)
How to create script which will enter password automatically?

```
#echo "Hello Admin"
#su root@admin
```

[image]

[image]

I just want to bash script and don't enter password.
Why does it ask me to enter password?

Comment: Having the root password in plain-text format in an executable script... I gather security is of no concern at all?

Comment: U can't fit in one line. But Idk how its possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible!
Not for that command, but you can create a sudo user with `ALL ALL: NO Password`, search online on how to cerate a sudo user to run `sudo` commands without password.

Comment: Yeah, U can't create script for that command.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to `su` without password, I recommend using `sudo su`. Allow the user to use `su` without password in `/etc/sudoers` with

`[username] ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/su`

or

`[username] ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

since the user can already do whatever he/she wants with root access. Benefit over passing cleartext password from script is that the `root` password isn't leaked out. Remember that the password may be readable after deleting the script.

EDIT:Sollution below doesn't work after all, `su` treats `stdin` as a command and exits after it. `echo 'passwd'|sudo -S [command]` works for most commands other than `su` but if you use it, note that `stdin` still has the password if `sudo` didn't ask for it because timestamp was still fresh. You can use `sudo -k` first to force password query.`sudo -k && echo 'passwd'|sudo -S [cmd]`. Still, better use `NOPASSWD` in `/etc/sudoers`.

<del>EDIT: Also, instead of using `NOPASSWD:`, you can also use `sudo -S` to read the `sudo` password from `stdin` and use something like `echo [password]|sudo -S su`. `sudo` takes the user password and needs permission to run `/bin/su` or `ALL` like above. Like all `sudo` commands, password expected is the user's password, not `root`'s</del>

Comment: **Well I used this method for the other user. But for this user I try to create script.**

Comment: @user3043926 will the edit work for you?

Comment: ** Do you have an example?**

Comment: @user3043926 `[username] ALL=(ALL) /bin/su` in `/etc/sudoers`, `echo [user password] | sudo -S su` in script to switch to root.

Comment: **In the the `etc/sudoers` I have user `borya ALL=(ALL) /bin/su`. In the script I typed `echo admin | sudo -S su` . Now I logged in under the user `borya` and run  the script. It shows me `admin: command not found.`

Comment: @user3043926 huh. subshell indeed treats stdin as command and exists after it. I can't figure out out to prevent that. I'll edit the answer to remove that. Sorry, should've tested it, assumed it worked since `sudo -S [command]` works and `NOPASSWD:` `sudo su` works.